# can I get available bytes to read from a Socket using Java NIO?

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I want to know if there are available bytes to be read in a Java NIO Socket. In C/C++ it can be done using something like this:

```
int available(int fd){
  long readable = 0;

    if (ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &readable) < 0){
      // error
    }

  return (int) readable;
}
```

It is possible to do the same operation with [Java NIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/package-summary.html) (using [SocketChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html), [Selector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/channels/Selector.html), [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/net/Socket.html), etc.)?

Comment: Why do you think you need to know? There are very few correct uses of this information.

Comment: let's assume I need to know it. it is a simple question, you don't need to know why.

Comment: It is indeed a simple question, but knowing why might well provoke someone to post an alternative technique, which might well be better. You don't have any reason to assume you have exhausted the universe of possibilities. And let's also assume that I might know some of those alternatives. Just for the sake of argument. And just reasserting that you 'need a way to do it' in the faces of responses that tell you it isn't possible is not a rational process of enquiry.

Comment: @EPJ, I have a single threaded application with multiple sockets open. I want to know in a moment the amount of bytes readable in each socket to start reading by one or another. I have a similar algorithm developed in C/C++ and I want exactly the same functionality in Java.

Comment: That's what Selector.select() is for, to tell you which channels are ready to read. So you were doing it the wrong way in C++ in the first place: *N* system calls instead of one. You can keep asking for something that doesn't exist for as long as you like, but it doesn't change the answer. You are wasting time.

Comment: My single thread is doing more things than read and write from sockets. Anyway, I can ask for more readable bytes in socket and I want to do the same in Java. I want to know if it is possible.

Comment: You've been asking that for two weeks; you've been told several times that it isn't; you've also been told about several alternatives, one at least of which is superior to what you're doing now in C++; you seem to be entirely averse to taking in what you're being told here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea behind NIO is to provide a way to wait for events (e.g. "connection has readable data ready") from any one of multiple connections at the same time, which sounds like exactly what you are looking for. Take a look at `java.nio.channels.Selector`. You basically register the "readable" event of all the connections you have with this selector object and then call one of three `select` methods that will wait for an event on one of your connections:

1. `select()` - blocks until an event is available (use if your program has nothing else to do)
2. `select(long timeout)` - blocks until an event is available or a timeout happens (use if you want to conserve CPU load and increase network responsiveness if it's OK if your program slows down a bit)
3. `selectNow()` - returns immediately (use if your program needs to keep running)

Then you use the `selectedKeys` method to grab a list of all connections that have an event waiting (for example, have data ready to be read). Then just iterate over this list and read from the connections with data only and ignore the other connections that aren't in the list as they have no data available.

This will allow you to check without blocking WHETHER data is available (is connection in the list or not), but not HOW MUCH data is available. But if you then do a read on the connection with data available, it will return immediately without blocking and return as much data as is available, if you've given it a big enough buffer. You can then choose to buffer this data somewhere and make the amount of data in the buffer available, but something tells me you don't really need this anyways and just want to go ahead and process the data.

Comment: I have been reading tons of documents and the best approximation I have found is to use `selectNow()` function and search for `OP_READ` `SelectionKey`. I am going to write it in an answer. Thank you for the idea!

Comment: Exactly right. If you need to actually get the number of immediately available bytes, you could write yourself a wrapper object around a ByteChannel that has an internal buffer. This wrapper could then provide the method you described in your original question by simply reading from itself into its internal buffer. If the channel is set to non-blocking, it will read only what's available immediately, even if that is nothing and return you the read length. This is then the count of available bytes. You then just need to read from your wrapper object's buffer rather than the original channel.

Comment: it sounds like the final solution, but in fact it implies reading from the socket. maybe is the unique solution to know the bytes in the buffer. thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Can't be done. An API is present, formally speaking, via `SocketChannel.socket().getInputStream().available()`, but `getInputStream()` operations will fail on a non-blocking channel, so it can't be used in your circumstance.

*EDIT:* Now that you've illuminated us a little, what you require still doesn't exist in Java, but as you are in non-blocking mode it doesn't matter in the slightest. Just read into a buffer that is at least as big as your socket receive buffer: the number of bytes read is the number of bytes that could have been read without blocking, which is exactly what you just did.

Comment: Could be a limitation. Anyway I think it is an issue related with the socket, not with an input stream related with the socket. A socket can have an input stream associated with it, or not; isn't it? Java NIO developers could implement something like that.

Comment: @logoff It *is* a limitation, and it *is* related to the input stream of a non-blocking socket. See for example [Channels.newInputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html#newInputStream(java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel)). There's no point in just arguing about it. When you try it you will see for yourself. If you want to debate my facts you need to produce some counter-evidence. Mere speculation is of no interest.

Comment: EJP is right, java NIO sockets aren't designed for this, if you want to use this aproach you will need Java IO. Note that this implementation will be far from optimal.

Answer (score 3):

I have read tons of documentation, forums and, obviously each of your responses. I have developed and tested a solution. It is not the best, but it is my best approximation.

I use [selectNow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#selectNow%28%29) method of [Selector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/channels/Selector.html). Given a `Selector` named `selector` that have a [SocketChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html) registered, I can use this method to know if the associated [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) has readable bytes:

```
public boolean isReadable() {
    try {
        selector.selectNow();
        Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
        Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = selectedKeys.iterator();
        while(keyIterator.hasNext()) {
            SelectionKey selectionKey = keyIterator.next();
            if(!selectionKey.isValid()) {
                continue;
            }
            if(selectionKey.isReadable()) {
                return true;
            }
            keyIterator.remove();
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        // error
    }
    return false;
}
```

It is the only way I have found to know if a Socket has readable bytes without reading the bytes. Do you know a better way to do it or disadvantages of doing it by this way?

**EDIT:**

This solution works the first time, but it has a drawback: it always returns true even if 0 bytes are readable. A socket can be readable even if no data is available. This is not the behaviour I want, because I don't want to read when there is no data in the read buffer.

**EDIT2 BIS:**

Test this code:

```
public static boolean isReadable(Selector selector) {
    try {
        selector.selectNow();
        Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
        Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = selectedKeys.iterator();
        while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {
            SelectionKey selectionKey = keyIterator.next();
            if (!selectionKey.isValid()) {
                continue;
            }
            if (selectionKey.isReadable()) {
                    keyIterator.remove();
                return true;
            }
            keyIterator.remove();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

public static void read() {
    try {
        Selector selector = Selector.open();
        SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();

        Socket socket = socketChannel.socket();

        System.out.println("Connecting to server...");
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9999));
        System.out.println("Connected to server.");

        socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);

        socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);

        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

        while (true) {
            boolean readable = isReadable(selector);
            if (readable) {
                System.out.println("Readable data found! Let's read...");
                bb.clear();
                int readBytes = socketChannel.read(bb);
                if (readBytes < 0) {
                    System.out.println("End of Stream found");
                    break;
                }
                byte[] readArray = new byte[readBytes];
                System.arraycopy(bb.array(), 0, readArray, 0, readBytes);
                System.out.println("Read (" + (readBytes) + " bytes): "
                        + new String(readArray, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                bb.flip();
                socketChannel.write(bb);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } else {
                System.out.println("No data to read, sleeping");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    read();
}
```

First of all, I execute an application that listens for connections and writes data: I used [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) with this command: `nc -l 9999`. Then I execute my Java program. Finally I can write text lines in `netcat` and my Java program works perfectly.

Remember it is a proof of concept, not a way to real programming solution. In fact, it is a very bad practise. Thank you @EJP and @Markus!

Comment: Re: EDIT: Really? That should definitely not be the case. Usually the READABLE flag should only get reset and returned again if you actually do a read. And it should only get returned again from selectNow if there is data available. This is probably some other issue in your code, although from a first glance at your code snippet I can't see any glaring problems.

Comment: @Markus I have tested my snippet and selectNow() returns always after the first positive. If I put the method in a loop, it loops without stop even if the sender doesn't send any data.

Comment: if you actually read the received data off the connection, it should stop returning immediately. The read request resets the READABLE flag. But if you simply call selectNow() again without reading then, yes, it will return again immediately since the data is still there waiting.

Comment: @Markus take a look of my 2nd edition, please. it shows the problem I explain. am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @logoff Re EDIT, you should remove the key from the selected key set before returning. However if you don't read, OP_READ will fire again, as it should. This is still *N* system calls instead of one. You should register all the channels with a single selector and have it tell you which channels are ready, instead of asking it one by one.

Comment: Thank you @EJP! I have added a line removing the SelectionKey. Now it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any method in NIO that does that. One just go ahead and read.

Comment: I need to know if there are bytes to read. That's why I put the answer.

Comment: @logoff "this can't be done" is a perfectly valid answer. I don't think it's fair to downvote an answer you didn't want to get. (As opposed to a factually incorrect one.)

Answer (score -3):

Bytebuffer.limit will return you the length available in the buffer.

```
sctpChannel.receive(byteBuffer, null, null);
byteBuffer.flip();

 if (byteBuffer.limit() > 0) 
  {
         .....................//Do your work here
    //             read the data in a byte array
    byteBuffer.clear();  
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. The question is about how much data can be read *without blocking,* which requires an interface to the TCP/IP stack, which isn't available via NIO. Not an answer.

Comment: I don't understand very well your response. Can you put the definition of the objects 'sctpChannel' and 'byteBuffer'?